# Varied batch file output when run with scheduler

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

```
 @echo off
 setLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
 pushd H:\reports\Revenue\ZREVEXP
 setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%G in ('dir/b/od') do (set newest=%%G)
 copy %newest% D:\FILES\zbookings_revenue\archivezbookings_revenue%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%.txt
 DEL D:\FILES\zbookings_revenue\zbookings_revenue.txt
 copy %newest% D:\FILES\zbookings_revenue\zbookings_revenue.txt
 REM PAUSE
 POPD
```

The batch file runs perfect manually but when I run it as a scheduled task I get the following odd results. The first is that the zbookings_revenue.txt file will contain the .bat file contents. So what you see above is copied to my zbookings_revenue.txt file. Another is that the output file grows to 33MB from a 6MB source file. Maybe there is something wrong with my batch code but I'm not sure how it runs fine through explorer all else being equal. Is there any way that the code above could produce these results? Thanks for the help!

Comment: If "h:" is a network drive, depending of the scheduled task configuration it is possible that the batch file is unable to see it, so, the `pushd` fails and the rest of the script is executed in the wrong folder

Comment: @MCND H: is a network folder. Does the `Start in` field effect this in the task scheduler?

Comment: drive maps are problematic under task scheduler as they are related to a session. Can you replace your `pushd` to something like `pushd \\server\share\folder....` ?

Comment: You will also need to give authentication in the scheduled task to use a network resource.  The system account does not have network access.

Comment: @foxidrive Thanks! I do have authentication included. Will this be a problem when my credentials are updated?

Comment: Look at the last four posts in this page: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/e8df9b57-4b84-40a5-a606-035a7bfcbfbd/changing-passwords-for-scheduled-tasks?forum=ITCG

Comment: @MCND if you want to throw it up in an answer I will accept.